# string type that will import a module that returns a kind

Tags: typescript

I want to define a trypescript function that takes a string and returns an object. The string is the path to a module to import using dynamic `import` or `require`. I would like the parameters type to be more specific than `string`, I would like it to be a type error if the string is not a path to a module of the expected kind.

```js
factory('./path/to/string-fn'); // should error, () => string not compatible with () => number.
factory('./path/to/number-fn');  // should not error

async function factory(path: T): Promise<number> {
  const {default: fn} = await import(path);
  return fn()
}
```

```js
# path/to/string-fn
export default function hello(): string {
  return 'hello';
}
```

```js
# path/to/number-fn
export default function zero(): string {
  return 0;
}
```

`type MODULE = typeof import('./path/to/number-fn')` resolves to the shape of the module but `type PATH = './path'; type MODULE = typeof import(PATH)` yields error 1141 String literal expected.

Answer (score 1):

If your paths are known in advance (i.e. at the point of defining your `factory` function), you could type your function like:

```js
type NumberFunctionPaths = "./path/to/number-fn" | "./path/to/other-number-fn";

async function factory(path: NumberFunctionPaths): Promise<number> {
  const {default: fn} = await import(path);
  return fn()
}
```

Note that this also works if you're calling `factory()` from a parent or subdirectory, because the path will stay relative to the factory function itself (because the import is located there).

---

Alternatively, if you can move the import itself to the caller, you could do it like this:

```js
interface NumberFuncModule {
    default: () => number;
}

async function factory(func: Promise<NumberFuncModule>): Promise<number> {
    const { default: fn } = await func;
    return fn();
}

factory(import("./number-fn"));
factory(import("./string-fn"));
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Type '() => string' is not assignable to type '() => number'
```

Comment: The set of paths are not known ahead if time

Comment: Added an alternative solution. If this also doesn't answer your question, I'm curious what you're trying to achieve with the factory. E.g. is your 'real' factory much more complex?

Comment: I'm writing a library that runs partially in a worker. I want users to inject their own dependencies, like a logger, from the main thread. You can't pass instances of classes thru the worker message port but you can pass a path to a module to load in the worker process.

Comment: I see. I don't think the way you want to type this is possible: you'd need something that uses `import(x)` in a type expression. However, this is only possible if `x` is a string literal. So one way or the other, the `import()` piece of it needs to be at the spot where you call your factory, for TypeScript to be able to determine the packag's shape.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a class sort of like this:

```
export class Path {
  constructor(private path: string) {
    if (!someTestForValidPath(path)) {
      throw new Error('Bad path! Bad!');
    }
  }

  toString(): string {
    return this.path;
  }
}
```

Then use this as your parameter for your factory function.

Comment: I'd like a compile time type error not a runtime error

Comment: You'd get both. You'd get a compile time error if you try to use anything except `Path` to pass the path. You'd get a runtime error if you try to create an invalid `Path` in the first place.

There is no typing so specific that it will give you compile-time errors for an invalid path string at every possible level of originally specifying a path, however.

Comment: You wouldn't get a compile error for `new Path('not-a-module')`, and that's what I really want. import('not-a-path')  has a type, but import is syntax, not a function, so the standard type tools don't help.